# mongodb, find -> how to pass a value to a query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have an already created and working mongodb database, and i have already created a collection under it named 'customers'
Under this collection, i have multiple already inserted dictionaries

I am connecting to it via mongopy via python, and i want to list all dictionaries which 'number' field is equal with my value. The value is not know yet.

one line from my dictionaries: 
{'_id': ObjectId('5d8641b89d8e8bde6b587693'), 'number': '123562', 'name': 'Viola', 'address': 'Sideway 1633'}

I have a text file, which contains only a number, and i store it into 'recognizednumber'
I have a different .py which needs to be implemented before i know what kind of value i want to search for. (thats creating the txt and writing a value into it.)

I am reading this number out from the .txt and storing it into "recognizednumber"

I would like to print out all of the dictionary lines from my collection, which 'number' field is matching with my 'recognizednumber' value.

If i printing out for test the recognized number value its showing:

```
['12352']
```

Unfortunately it does not showing any matched values when printing out the mydoc dictionaries so i assume its there is not a match.

Could someone help please, how do i pass "not known yet" values into a query?

many thanks in advance.

Update::

looks like the problem will be with:
 - when reading from the file, my value if i print out: ['12345']
 - if I manually set a value :   12345

```
    'define which collection'
    mycol = mydb["customers"]
    'search for recognized number'
    recognizednumber = open(FilePaths.fnRecognized, "r",encoding="UTF8").readlines()
    print(recognizednumber)

    myquery = {"number": recognizednumber}

    mydoc = mycol.find(myquery)

    for x in mydoc:
        print(x)
```

Comment: Are you sure your python connects to the database properly? I suggest you to try to insert a bogus record(document) using your python program to be sure.

Comment: I tested it in a different .py to connect to it, its working.

Comment: randomname = "William"
myquery2 = {"name": randomname}
mydoc2 = mycol.find(myquery2)
for x2 in mydoc2:
    print(x2)

Tested like this for name, and its showing me a lot of dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to pass in the string without any of the extra quotes or brackets; you can strip these out with something like:

```
recognizednumber = recognizednumber[2:-2]
```

See if this works:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
mydb = client['yourdatabase']
mycol = mydb["customers"]

mycol.insert_one({'number': '123562', 'name': 'Viola', 'address': 'Sideway 1633'})

recognizednumber = "['123562']"
recognizednumber = recognizednumber[2:-2]
print(recognizednumber)
myquery = {"number": recognizednumber}
mydoc = mycol.find(myquery)

for x in mydoc:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I had to double strip

```
recognizednumber = str(recognizednumber).strip('[]')
recognizednumber = str(recognizednumber).strip("'")
```

Comment: No problem, thank you for looking into this. actually your solution stripped my string and if i print it out its showing me:  []